# Webview does not load AdSense ads

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, ads, adsense

I use WebView in my Android app and AdSense ads don't appear when I go to a site. My webview code:

```
webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH;
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
String url = "http://solante.pw/";
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Log Records:

> -netbsd: getaddrinfo: googleads.g.doubleclick.net get result from proxy gai_error = 0
>   I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The resource https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20181031/r20180604/show_ads_impl.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.", source:  (0)
>   I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The resource https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20181031/r20180604/show_ads_impl.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.", source:  (0)

Ads appear when I go to the same URL as Google Chrome tabs are, when I enter Google Chrome, the ads appear. I think I need to add a setting, but I don't know about it.
[Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58vlP.jpg)

Comment: Do you have any updates about this? I have same issue

Comment: any update on this issue ?